# How to reorder 2D matrix axes based on reordering of a vector in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, data-science

I have a `2D ndarray`, shaped `(n_x, n_t)`

The 2D matrix stores along its rows (so horizontally, for each line) a quantity `Q`, so a discrete version of a function of `t`, for fixed `x`.
Across its columns, so for fixed `t`, (i.e. down a fixed column), the 2D matrix saves that quantity's `Q` values for different `x`'s, so I have a discrete version of `Q(x)`.

I will be plotting this matrix as a 2D heatmap.

I have a vector shaped `(n_t, )` which contains the times for which the 2D matrix stores the quantity `Q`'s values, for any given x values. So for each row, across the columns, the times underlying those values from the 2D matrix are the same.

Visually, for `n_x=3` and `n_t=3`:

```
[
[Q_{11}, Q_{12}, Q_{13}],
[Q_{21}, Q_{22}, Q_{23}],
[Q_{31}, Q_{32}, Q_{33}]
]
```

The row `[Q11, Q12, Q13]` is basically `Q(x_1, ts)`, the row `[Q21, Q22, Q23]` is basically `Q(x_2, ts)` and similarly for the last row.

I have `ts` as: `[t1, t2, t3]`.

**Problem**:

I reorder `ts` (for whatever reason) to be `[t2, t3, t1]`.

I want to reorder the matrix as:

```
[
[Q_{12}, Q_{13}, Q_{11}], 
[Q_{22}, Q_{23}, Q_{21}], 
[Q_{31}, Q_{33}, Q_{32}]
]
```

How shall I do it? What shall I read about?
The reordering of the `ts` vector comes from: `np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftreq(ts))`.

Thank you!

**EDIT from comments:**

```
a = np.array([
            [1, 2, 3], 
            [4, 5, 6], 
            [7, 8, 9]
            ])

ts = np.array([100, 200, 300])

tss = np.array([200, 300, 100])

aa = np.array([
            [2, 3, 1], 
            [5, 6, 4], 
            [8, 9, 7]
            ])
```

Comment: Nice explanation! Could you you add a (toy) input and the expected output?

Comment: @DaniMesejo, thank you. Do you mean to actually throw some floats inside the Q_{ab}'s so that you can apply the code you write and see the result? I don't have an input output example at the moment, as I don't know how to reorder the matrix based on the ``ts`` reordering

Comment: Yep. That is correct

Comment: @DaniMesejo, see the edited question and please tell me if that's what you are looking for

Comment: You don't have an array of shuffled indices when you reorder?

Comment: So `aa = a[:, [1,2,0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
            [1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6],
            [7, 8, 9]
            ])

ts = np.array([100, 200, 300])
tss = np.array([200, 300, 100])


# number of rows n_x in the original question
n_x = a.shape[0]

# find the original positions
indices = (ts == tss[:, None]).argmax(1)

res = np.take_along_axis(a, np.tile(indices, (n_x, 1)), axis=1)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[2 3 1]
 [5 6 4]
 [8 9 7]]
```